# Data should get replace as per lookup table

Tags: mysql, sql

Following is my sqlfiddle for testing and building the query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/975c6/1

What I have been trying to do is to detect if Table1 column ADRES  `house#  240 st. #  76 Cantt. road Chicago contains any value present in wrong column in lookup table that should get replaced by right column value.

Table1:

```
Username | Adres
Jhon     | house#  240 st. #  76 Cantt. road Chicago
```

Look up table:

```
WRONG   |    Right
house#       HNO
```

For example : `house#  240 st. #  76 Cantt. road Chicago` (house# is wrong so it should gets replaced by HNO)and update `Table 1` and set address to

```
Jhon     | HNO  240 st. #  76 Cantt. road Chicago
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to update the fields,

```
 UPDATE table1 a CROSS JOIN lookup b
 SET    a.ADRES = REPLACE(a.ADRES, b.`WRONG`, b.`RIGHT`)
 WHERE  a.ADRES LIKE CONCAT('%', b.`WRONG`, '%')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fb2a/2)

but if you want only to project the replaced value,

```
 SELECT  a.Username, REPLACE(a.ADRES, b.`WRONG`, b.`RIGHT`)
 FROM    table1 a CROSS JOIN lookup b
 WHERE   a.ADRES LIKE CONCAT('%', b.`WRONG`, '%')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39ff2/1)

Comment: Thanks, kindly let me know if there are multiple fields that i wanted to update same in one table as per lookup vlues so i should run the sql for each fields separately or i can do it with one sql too for all?

Comment: this should do, one sql for all

Comment: but be careful that index will now be used in this case.

Comment: okay then i have to addup set and where , set and where for each column, like `update table1 set adress where adress = that set  username where username = that` .  RIGHT?

Comment: Just one last question what would be my query if i want to update two columns with one query `like as you updated house number also update username = jhon to jhonny`(Regardless of, if there is error value for house number exist or not). That would be so nice of you if you give me heads up that way.. Thanks.

Comment: you mean you have also another lookup table for the username or the same table for the house no?

Comment: no lookup table contains all the wrong values and they needed to be replaced by right one so i want to check accordingly . Like (Update this column if thats wrong , Update that column if this is wrong ) with one sql query. Trying to perform update in such manner. There are fields in which i am also performing checks that either if its value > 100 then it should get replaced by 100 (currently its being done by one sql query and i want to embed it with the solution you provided). `Do you want me to post new QUESTION FOR THIS ONE?`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834614/one-update-query-for-all-updates `NEW QUESTION , Kindly see if you can help`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20986/discussion-between-kuya-john-and-soft-genic)

Comment: A slight problem OCCURED WITH YOUR old solution kindly take  a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14285/1 and see james house number is not converting as per right value

Comment: by definition, `REPLACE` is `CASE SENSITIVE`.

Comment: here's an article the creates a user define `REPLACE` function that is case insensitive. http://pento.net/2009/02/15/case-insensitive-replace-for-mysql/