# One Update query for all updates

Tags: mysql

Following are my sql queries that are updating values in same table. I want to embed these two query in one and i was unable to do that. Kindly let me know how can i do so , Thanks:

```
$SQL1 = "UPDATE table1  SET gender='$sex', dob = '$dob', reg_date ='$reg_date'
    WHERE id = '$id'"

$SQL2 = "UPDATE table1 a CROSS JOIN lookup b
 SET    a.ADRES = REPLACE(a.ADRES, b.`WRONG`, b.`RIGHT`)
 WHERE  a.ADRES LIKE CONCAT('%', b.`WRONG`, '%')"
```

Comment: How are these tables related?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/975c6/1 this is my sql fiddle

Comment: Some columns of Table are being updated as per lookup table i created in the above mentioned sql fiddle, Can i perform something like if else in update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  table1 a CROSS JOIN lookup b
 SET    a.ADRES = REPLACE(a.ADRES, b.`WRONG`, b.`RIGHT`),
        gender='$sex', 
        dob = '$dob', 
        reg_date ='$reg_date'
 WHERE  a.ADRES LIKE CONCAT('%', b.`WRONG`, '%') OR 
        id = '$id'
```

the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please see the article below to lear how to protect from it,

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: ok if i make the queries separately will  it gonna effect the speed as compare to one query for all??

Comment: A slight problem OCCURED WITH YOUR old solution kindly take  a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14285/1 and see james house number is not converting as per right value

Comment: This will set the gender, dob, and reg_date on rows that should only set adres, and vice versa.